# How to run jobs based on the pull request branch

Tags: github

I have 2 jobs in my workflow 'Plan and Apply". I want plan to run when there is pull request on my testing branch and Apply to run when there is a pull request on master branch. Below is the snippet of my code. This workflow doesn't run,I am getting message " This check was skipped" .What I'm i doing wrong?

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - testing
      - master

jobs:
  plan:
    name: "Terraform Plan"
    if: ${{ github.head_ref == 'testing'}}

 Apply:
  name: "Run Terraform Apply"
  if: ${{ github.head_ref == 'master'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to instead of putting it all into one workflow file, to create two separate ones, where you then only specify the branch you want, for example:

```
`plan_testing.yml`

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - testing

jobs:
  plan:
    name: "Terraform Plan"
```

This achieves the same outcome while keeping them more easily separated and simpler to audit their run history in GitHub Actions.

You can find out more about GitHub Actions and how to configure them by [checking out their awesome docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions).

Comment: the requirement is to have them in one workflow. please how can I achieve that with this concept?